# dump analysis: Module is shown as unknown in stack-trace although all symbols available

Tags: c#, c++, windbg, stack-trace, mixed-mode

I have a problem with the latest dump analyses I am doing. In several dump files when I use the command:

```
!analyze -v
```

I get information on the exception stack. It is an AccessViolationException. Stack is something like this:

```
00000000 00000000 unknown.dll!MyComLib.MyCtl.set_ShowInfo+0x1
0028dc5c 00000000 unknown.dll!AxMyComLib.AxCtl.set_ShowInfo+0x1a
0028dc68 00000000 unknown.dll!Company.Client.Utility.set_Options+0x35
0028dc78 00000000 unknown.dll!Company.Client.Utility.SetAvailable+0x1a
0028dc84 00000000 unknown.dll!Company.Client.System.client_Available+0x1df
```

It is calling from .NET into a COM ActiveX Component. Both are developed by us. And this short callstack runs through 3 dlls. .NET->Wrapper->Com(->Error)

I know the module (and it is not called unknown ;) ).
I have all the symbols and they are correctly set up and loaded.

If I use `u unknown.dll!MyComLib.MyCtl.set_ShowInfo+0x1` naturally that does not work. But even if I replace unknown by the correct module name it does not work.

What I would like to find out is the correct source line where the exception is thrown (+0x1).

My Questions:
Why does it show up as unknown?
How can I find out at what line of code the problem occurs?

I haven't had the problem before with the "unknown" Module entries in dumps I analysed.

**Update**

Some more information: 
Exception related frames on Thread 0 result of ~0kb1000:

```
ChildEBP RetAddr  Args to Child              
0028ea28 72ac90f7 e0434352 00000001 00000005 KERNELBASE!RaiseException+0x58
0028eacc 72c00b0c 00000000 73dc63b0 0028eaf0 clr!RaiseTheExceptionInternalOnly+0x276
0028eae4 72c00d3d 00000004 0028ee98 72ac957e clr!RaiseTheException+0x86
0028eb0c 72c00d6d 00000004 004e4790 00000000 clr!RaiseTheExceptionInternalOnly+0x30a
0028eb40 72d03512 00184270 004e4790 00000000 clr!RealCOMPlusThrow+0x2f
0028eb98 72d03a75 0028eda8 00184270 00184270 clr!ThrowInvokeMethodException+0xac
0028eea4 71c03781 00000000 027d25d4 71c0b790 clr!RuntimeMethodHandle::InvokeMethod+0xa64
0028eec8 71c38f9d 00000000 00000000 027d24a8 mscorlib_ni+0x2d3781
0028ef18 729e2952 004e4790 0028ef78 72a0318f mscorlib_ni+0x308f9d
0028ef24 72a0318f 0028efc4 0028ef68 72ac957e clr!CallDescrWorkerInternal+0x34
0028ef78 72a039d5 0028f0c0 00000001 00000000 clr!CallDescrWorkerWithHandler+0x6b
0028eff8 72aaef24 0028f0f4 11ce1352 001837d8 clr!MethodDescCallSite::CallTargetWorker+0x152
0028f124 72aaf048 00000000 00000001 11ce134e clr!RunMain+0x1aa
0028f398 72b0a484 00000000 11ce11de 013c0000 clr!Assembly::ExecuteMainMethod+0x124
0028f89c 72b0a527 11ce1a8e 00000000 00000000 clr!SystemDomain::ExecuteMainMethod+0x614
0028f8f8 72b0a63a 11ce1b4e 00000000 00000000 clr!ExecuteEXE+0x4c
0028f938 72b0c3c2 11ce1b02 00000000 00000000 clr!_CorExeMainInternal+0xdc
0028f974 7308f5a3 11cee72d 00000000 76371222 clr!_CorExeMain+0x4d
0028f9ac 73107efd 0028f9c4 73107f16 00000000 mscoreei!_CorExeMain+0x10a
0028f9c4 73104de3 00000000 7637337a fffde000 mscoree!ShellShim__CorExeMain+0x7d
0028f9cc 7637337a fffde000 0028fa18 77809882 mscoree!_CorExeMain_Exported+0x8
0028f9d8 77809882 fffde000 64decd1b 00000000 kernel32!BaseThreadInitThunk+0xe
0028fa18 77809855 73104ddb fffde000 00000000 ntdll!__RtlUserThreadStart+0x70
0028fa30 00000000 73104ddb fffde000 00000000 ntdll!_RtlUserThreadStart+0x1b
```

`~*e!clrstack` does not have any exception related info on the threads. `!dumpstack` neither.

`!threads` shows:

```
       ID OSID ThreadOBJ    State GC Mode     GC Alloc Context  Domain   Count Apt Exception
   0    1 21e8 004e4790     26020 Preemptive  73DF4F30:00000000 004dd3a0 0     STA System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException 73dc63b0
```

when I `!pe` until I get the internal exception it is the AccessViolationException stack from the beginning of the question.

**Update 2**
`~0e !clrstack` shows:

```
0028eb24 74f6c42d [GCFrame: 0028eb24] 
0028eb5c 74f6c42d [GCFrame: 0028eb5c] 
0028ebe0 74f6c42d [HelperMethodFrame_PROTECTOBJ: 0028ebe0] System.RuntimeMethodHandle.InvokeMethod(System.Object, System.Object[], System.Signature, Boolean)
0028eeb4 71c03781 System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.UnsafeInvokeInternal(System.Object, System.Object[], System.Object[])
0028eed8 71c38f9d System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.Invoke(System.Object, System.Reflection.BindingFlags, System.Reflection.Binder, System.Object[], System.Globalization.CultureInfo)
0028ef18 0033005f Program.Main() [d:\prg\Program.cs @ 20]
0028f0a4 729e2952 [GCFrame: 0028f0a4]
```

The exception was (- sic! :( ) relatively good to reproduce on a test pc. Unfortunately not on a development machine (with or without debugger attached). Currently it vanished again. I have about 6 dumps that all show the same exception and nearly the same stacktrace.

**Update 3**
`!teb` shows the following information on thread 0:

```
TEB at fffdd000
    ExceptionList:        0028eabc
    StackBase:            00290000
    StackLimit:           00283000
    SubSystemTib:         00000000
    FiberData:            00001e00
    ArbitraryUserPointer: 00000000
    Self:                 fffdd000
    EnvironmentPointer:   00000000
    ClientId:             000016e8 . 000021e8
    RpcHandle:            00000000
    Tls Storage:          0ca60888
    PEB Address:          fffde000
    LastErrorValue:       6
    LastStatusValue:      c0000034
    Count Owned Locks:    0
    HardErrorMode:        0
```

Comment: @Thomas `lm` shows correctly all modules. the module in question has private pdb symbols loaded (from the place I expect it to). ´.symopt´ has 0x30337 so 0x40 is not included. I wouldn't expect it necessary (0x40) as I have all pdbs from the build server and they are loaded but I will try. And it is an inproc server.

Comment: @Thomas .symopt did not change anything on the output. I assume the dump somehow does not really have the full information anymore on the stack. But I would like to find out the real source location where it fails with the AccessViolation. It would help to pinpoint the potential problem.

Comment: I believe the second column should either be the base pointer (EBP) or the return address. Either way, zero raises a red flag about stack corruption. What does manually dumping all the stacks show? `~*kb1000`

Comment: @MarcSherman That shows all the stacks. No problem there (including module names). But the result noted inside the question above is from ´analyze -v´ so it is essentially the result of ´pe´ print exception. This stack is not available anymore on the threads I guess.

Comment: Did any of those stacks have any exception related frames on them? Does `~*e !clrstack` show anything useful?

Comment: @MarcSherman Added the info to the question

Comment: What does `~0e !clrstack` show?

Comment: @MarcSherman Added in update 2.

Comment: What's your source code at and around line 20 of d:\prg\Program.cs?

Comment: @MarcSherman that is only startup code (showing the main window like). It has nothing to do with the crash and is always like this when the program is running. Until something gets marshalled to the GUI thread. Thats where the crash stack comes from. But only by extracting out of the exception objects. Once the marshalling ended the stack of thread 0 is like what you see in the information again. That is my problem. There is just not more information anymore on the 0 thread of what has happened and I cannot extract the exact source line from the exception information of +0x1

Comment: +0x1 is just very strange because functions don't usually have one byte instructions at the very beginning. What does `!teb` show as the base and limit for that thread's call stack?

Comment: @MarcSherman Added them in update 3

Comment: Your stack addresses all fall within the base and limit range so they're fine. The only thing I can think of is to explore what is happening at `clr!RuntimeMethodHandle::InvokeMethod+0xa64` because that's the code throwing the exception.